# How to use firestore in firebase functions with express?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on project where I'm using express in firebase functions to run server side rendering pages using handlebars, Everything working perfectly but when I use firestore admin sdk I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

I'm using this code in my functions/index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express')
const engines = require('consolidate')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const serviceAccount = require('./lendme360-firebase-adminsdk-easkh-d9130c0494.json');
var admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
})

const stripe = require('stripe')('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
const db = admin.firestore()
const app = express()
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars)
app.set('views', './views')
app.use(cookieParser())
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
...
...
...
...
...
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Function is working properly but when try to const db = admin.firestore() gives me error I also tried emulators for both functions and firestore and still getting the same error

Please help me What I'm doing wrong here

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue, it seems that the module is not loaded in your environment. I could notice that you mentioned that you used other environments to test this.

In a local environment try to run the a test in which you just initialize the module with "const db = admin.firestore()" you should get the same error as before, but they I would ask to run "npm install firebase-admin --save" as per this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize), this gets the module to be used with node js.

In firebase functions you should have defined your modules at your package.json as per this other [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#initialize-firebase-sdk-for-cloud-functions), this should solve the error message that is telling us that node is not recognizing the syntax or the command from the module (as the module is not loaded).

Comment: I was using yarn package manger in functions directory. reinstalled the dependencies with npm install --save and it really worked thank you so much Luis Manuel